# how to convert 3/4 into 9/8 time

Tags: notation

In this exercise I am given a piece of music in 3/4 and asked to convert it into 9/8. In 3/4 time each beat is a crotchet snd in 9/8 each beat is supposed to be a dotted crotchet but in the exercise the first part has been completed and the writer has left the crotchet as a normal crotchet beat. Can someone please explain to me if this is an error in the book or if I am making a mistake somewhere. I have attempted to do the exercise as you can see here.
[image]

Comment: Don't you just put the dot in (crotchet, 1st bar)? And surely the 1st bar is short anyway?

Comment: I would say the first part has been started but not completed. Add the dot as part of your assignment. Everything else looks good.

Comment: @Tim, thats what I thought... and it is not an anacrusis either because the last bar is complete. Very confusing if you ask me. They should have put that dot on the crotchet in 9/8

Comment: Seems like a duff question to me. Not the first, and certainly won't be the last. If the last bar is full, then it's not a well thought out question. What answer *is* shown?

Comment: @armani the last visible bar may not be the last bar of the piece, and the practice of compensating for the duration anacrusis at the end of the phrase is far from universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has indeed been started, but the answerer only got as far as the 3rd note written, and didn't finish that off. It needs a dot after it - making the last dotted crotchet in that bar.

As a question in an exam paper (?) I think it's poorly written - a rest at the beginning makes it read better. I understand it's sometimes eschewed these days, but to count in at the beginning it is much clearer with that rest, and at what cost?

That apart, your answer is fine. Wonder what the actual answer looks like?